# what does the [ux] tag mean?

Tags: discussion

Will someone please define the [ux](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux) tag? It's not self explanatory.

*(((Hmmm, looks like I need to add an extra sentence to allow the question to be posted. Let's see if this is enough.)))*

Comment: thank you, person who did so ;-)

Comment: Over at stack overflow `ux` is a synonym of `user-experience`, perhaps we should adopt the same here to avoid confusion in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-experience

Answer (score 4):

The problem with "ux" is that very few people would think to type it when trying to tag a relevant question.  To help with that, I created a "userexperience" synonym.  Although it's long, it will cause the "ux" tag to be raised as a suggestion whenever anybody starts typing a tag beginning with "us...".  Try it!

Comment: Not to be confused with [Un*x](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UN-asterisk-X.html), or one of its flavors - [HP-UX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX).

Answer (score 4):

Just noticed this site https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Given the way the general public embraced web maps once the neogeographers made them *[slippy](http://fantomplanet.wordpress.com/2005/06/23/definition-slippy-map/)*, I think this is an important tag.

Comment: I highly recommend the UX-SE site. Most GIS people are clued up around map design, but I have had some great inspiration around GIS application design from reading UX-SE.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Tags link under the **Geographic Information Systems meta** header line, then search on **ux** which reveals "about how a person feels about using a product, system or service."  That is all I could find ... but I have no clue if that is good or bad (aka uch or yuck or equivalent gutteral expression)

Comment: Hi Dan, that's because someone filled out the tag info, it used be empty. They just neglected to say anything here to indicate the request had been fulfilled.

Comment: @Matt, for the interim, perhaps we can go with my gutteral expression suggestion :)